# Create Group permission to grant view of all group content

Tags: 8, group

I'm running Drupal 8.7.11 and Group 8.x-1.0-rc5.

I have a situation whereby I have > 5,000 groups.  The majority of the users are members of 10 groups.  However I have a small set of users who need an overview of all content from all groups.  I have had issues running the site when enrolling users into all of the groups, so I had to give them 'Bypass group access control' in order that they can use the site without it crashing.

However what I would like to do is create a new 'View all group content' permission, which skips the access check, but doesn't give the users the administrative access that comes with 'Bypass group access control'.

Does anyone have an example of how this might be achieved?

Comment: Isn't that explained in their FAQ? https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/group/the-permission-layers-explained#s-i-want-my-site-admins-to-be-able-to-administer-all-groups-without-having-to-join-them

Comment: You're right! Thank you. I'm not sure how I missed the Advanced outsider permissions tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per their documentation "[The permission layers explained](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/group/the-permission-layers-explained#s-i-want-my-site-admins-to-be-able-to-administer-all-groups-without-having-to-join-them)" it should work like this:

> I want my site admins to be able to administer all groups without having to join them.
>
> Assign them a global role, e.g.: "Site admin", and then assign the "Administer group" >permission to the matching advanced outsider role in the group type configuration >section. Anyone with the "Site admin" role set to their account will be able to >administer all groups they are not a member of.